# How to Combine Two Seperate List in To List of Object

Tags: dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, dart-null-safety

How to convert two Seperate list into List of Object in Fluter,dart

```
class Task {

String name;
bool isDone
Task({this.name,this.isDone = false});

}
```

How To Convert this two List in to List as below mention

```
List<String> taskname = ['buy  milk','go to school','go to gym'];
List<bool> taskname = [true,false,true];
```

i want to Convert like this

```
List<Task>  taskList = [

Task(name: 'buy milk',isDone : true),
Task(name: 'go to school',isDone : false),
Task(name: 'buy milk',isDone : true),

];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```dart
var taskList = [for (var i = 0; i < taskname.length; i++) 
  Task(name: taskname[i], isDone: taskdone[i])
];
```